# 0-20mA to voltage conversion. Is this circuit OK?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current-sensing

Is this circuit OK, in your opinion?

[image: schematic diagram]
[image]

Comment: OK for what exactly? This circuit doesn't really show anything, just some inputs to a chip.

Comment: 0 to 3V output on CL_OUT

Comment: At the very least you are missing a bypass cap on V+, but I'm still not clear on what you want. You want to convert 0-20mA to 0-3V? Why use a current shunt monitor for that? You just need a resistor, unless you want to drive some sort of load?

Comment: What's your reference voltage? You will get 3 V + Vref out with 20 mA thru the resistor.

Comment: What voltage is CL_REF? What does 3V3 do? What is the expected supply voltage range, and how does it get to R25?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It can be GND or 3V depending on the current direction. Jumper selectable

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are missing the bypass capacitor.
It's unclear whether you have 3V3 or 5V as supply voltage. If it's 3V3, keep the voltage reference tied to ground as you only have an output margin of 0.1 V below Vss.
Except choosing the right gain, there's no magic.

Comment: There is a bypass capacitor -it is just in another place of the schematics with all other bypass ones (about 30) :)

Comment: It shouldn't be in another place on the schematic, keep bypass caps near their parts so you don't forget that they go near their parts on the PCB. Bypass caps should (almost) always be as close to the chip as possible.

Comment: @RonBeyer on the schematics doesn't mean on the PCB. They are off course close to the ICs. I group them all on the symbolic schematic in one place and then "spread" when design the PCB